# Disable network device for specified period of time

Tags: network, snow-leopard, ssh

Recently I converted an old MacBook into a server, running OS X 10.6.8 (the normal, non-server edition). I use it as my VPN server, my bittorrent rsync server, web server, ssh server and so forth.

Sometimes I manually disconnect the LAN cable from my server to speed up my connection for online gaming, afterwards I plug back the LAN cable.

What is a good way to temporary disable the LAN device on my MacBook running OS X 10.6.8? Preferably that it automatically enables again after a specified period of time (some sort of timer). I would prefer a method via SSH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Selfcontrol

[Selfcontrol](http://selfcontrolapp.com) is an app build for a different purpose, it disables your network connectivity for a certain amount of time to keep you from visiting social websites and keep you more productive. It makes it possible for you to create a `white-list` or a `black-list` to allow or block certain ip-adress/sites.

So I login to the server, set Selfcontrol to 1h. Now my internet connection from my server is disabled for 1h and will automatically come back afterwards.

[image: selfcontrol icon]

Answer (score 0):

If you disable your LAN device, you won't be able to log on SSH again.

If you need just to disable internet access for this machine, you could remove the default gateway with: `sudo route delete default` and add with `sudo route add default GATEWAY_IP`.

Comment: I know I need LAN for SSH, for that reason I thought it was a good idea to specify the time before hand. I'll give `route` a try.