# SelfControl not blocking anything

Tags: macos, applications, firewall

I have used SelfControl to block the internet for some time, but now it won't block anything anymore. *(Edit: Well, acutally one moment SelfControl blocks some sites, then allows them again, apparently randomly.)*

When I `ipfw list` while a block (with a handful of whitelisted sites) is running, there aren't the usual entries that SelfControl writes anymore. What I notice that SelfControl now takes a loooong time to start the counter when I click "Start". While it worked, the counter appeared immediately.

How can I troubleshoot that problem?

I don't have stealth mode activated in the Firewall, although my Firewall is active (and has been, while SelfControl worked).

I'm using SelfControl 2.0 under OS 10.9.5, but had the same problem with SelfControl 1.5 this morning.

---

Edit:

I have LittleSnitch installed and note that SelfControl connects to six of the 28 whitelisted URLs every minute.

Comment: Have you tried SelfControl on another user account? Do not set any sites on the white or blacklist.

Comment: What version are you running?

Comment: I edited the quesion. SC 2.0 and 1.5 both have that problem. I went to the Guest Account, but cannot set up a block there as the current block is still running there, too. Yes, this site should be blocked right now! Every now and then it is blocked, but then I can access it again ...

Comment: I [noticed](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/140238/disable-network-device-for-specified-period-of-time) that SelfControl lets you block outside IP's, but never blocks local IP addresses. Is it possible that you have some proxy running on your network as well? Or have your DNS settings using a local IP address?